# Same messages being passed more that once while switching tabs fast : Chrome extension issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am currently new to building the chrome extension. However I have started to build a chrome extension that scrapes a webpage and stores the data in the google spreadsheet.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "A listener check",
  "description": "Understanding the working of listeners in the application",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://some.website.com/projects/*",
        "http://some.website.com/projects/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://embedded_website.net/*",
        "https://embedded_website_2.net/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "demeter.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background":{
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "management",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Here is my background.js file

```
const loadedTabs = [];
const switchedTabs = [];

function updatedCallbackFunction(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    const message = {
        action: "load_page",
        changeInfo: changeInfo,
        tab: tab,
        allowLoad: 1,
        state: "loaded"
    }
    if (!loadedTabs.includes(tab.id))
        loadedTabs.push(tab.id);
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, message);
        });
    }

}

function tabActivatedCallbackFunction(activeInfo) {
    const message = {
        action: "load_page",
        activeInfo: activeInfo,
        state: "switched",
        allowLoad: 1
    }
    console.log(`Switched Tabs : ${switchedTabs}`)
    if (!switchedTabs.includes(activeInfo.tabId) ) {
        switchedTabs.push(activeInfo.tabId);
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeInfo.tabId, message);
        });
    }
}

async function backgroundRuntimeCallbackFunction(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case "unload":
            console.log('Wrong page loaded');
            break;
        case "listen":
            console.log('Investigating current page');
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "load_page"});
            })
            break;
        case "demeter_page_direct":
            console.log('Going to demeter page');
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {...message, action: 'demeter_page_load'});
            });
            break;
        case "wait_for_page_load":
            console.log('Waiting for demeter page load');
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {...message, action: 'demeter_page_load'});
            });
            break;
        case "upload_google_sheet":
            console.log('Updating to google sheet');
            const {action, allowLoad, QApresent, ...googleSheetData} = message;
            console.log(googleSheetData);
            googleSheetData.hitlink = googleSheetData.hitlink.substring(0, googleSheetData.hitlink.lastIndexOf('&'));
            const options = {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(googleSheetData)
            }
            const response = await fetch('my_backend_app.com/url_to_fetch', options);
            const responseBody = await response.json();
            console.log(responseBody);
            const boxUpdateMessage = {
                ...message,
                action: "load_page",
                allowLoad: 0
            };
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, boxUpdateMessage);
            });
            break;
    }
}

// creating the functions to get the listeners

function tabUpdateFunction() {
    if (chrome.tabs.onUpdated.hasListener(updatedCallbackFunction)) {
        console.log('The onupdated listener is already there so removing it!');
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(updatedCallbackFunction);
    }
    // adding the onupdated listener again
    console.log('No overhead update function');
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updatedCallbackFunction);
}

function tabSwitchFunction() {
    if (chrome.tabs.onActivated.hasListener(tabActivatedCallbackFunction)) {
        console.log('The tab switch function already there so removing it');
        chrome.tabs.onActivated.removeListener(tabActivatedCallbackFunction);
    }
    console.log('No overhead switch function');
    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(tabActivatedCallbackFunction);
}

function backgroundRuntimeFunction() {
    console.log(`backgroundRuntimeFunction : ${chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(backgroundRuntimeCallbackFunction)}`);
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(backgroundRuntimeCallbackFunction);
    if (chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(backgroundRuntimeCallbackFunction)) {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(backgroundRuntimeCallbackFunction);
    }

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(backgroundRuntimeCallbackFunction);
}


// calling the functions
tabUpdateFunction();
tabSwitchFunction();
backgroundRuntimeFunction();
```

Here is content.js

```
function getDetails(msg) {
    // extract info
    return {
        action: 'demeter_page_direct',
        // more info
    };
}



function contentRuntimeCallback(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (message.action) {


        case "load_page":
            const delimiterMessage = getDetails(message);

            if (delimiterMessage.title) {
                const returnBtnForms = document.getElementsByClassName('force-inline');
                for (let returnBtnForm of returnBtnForms) {
                    returnBtnForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                        console.log('Return btn was clicked!');
                        e.preventDefault();
                        delimiterMessage.return = 1;
                        delimiterMessage.allowLoad = 0;
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(delimiterMessage);
                    })
                }
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(delimiterMessage);
            }
            else {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...delimiterMessage, action: 'unload'});
            }
            break;
    }
}

function contentRuntimeCheck() {
    if (chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(contentRuntimeCallback))
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(contentRuntimeCallback);
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(contentRuntimeCallback);
}

contentRuntimeCheck();
```

and demeter.js

```
function demeterRuntimeCallbackFunction(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case "demeter_page_load":
            if (message.hittitle.includes("specifictitle")) {
                const svgParentContainer = document.getElementById('SVG_PARENT_CONTAINER');
                if (!svgParentContainer) {
                    console.log('svg container loading!');
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...message, action: 'wait_for_page_load'});
                    break;
                } else {
                    // counting the total number of boxes
                    const totalBoxes = svgParentContainer.querySelectorAll('rect').length;
                 
                    // when page loads for the first time
                    if (message.allowLoad === 1) {
                        if (message.changeInfo)
                            console.log('Updated info done');
                        else if (message.currentTabInfo)
                            console.log('In port 1');
                        console.log(`still allowing to load`);
                        message.allowLoad = 0;
                        const finalSheetUploadMessage = {
                            ...message,
                            action: 'upload_google_sheet',
                            boxcount: totalBoxes
                        }
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(finalSheetUploadMessage);
                        break;
                    } else if (message.return === 1) {
                        console.log('In port 2');
                        const finalSheetUploadMessage = {
                            ...message,
                            hitqueue: message.hitqueue - 1,
                            action: 'upload_google_sheet',
                            boxcount: totalBoxes
                        }
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(finalSheetUploadMessage);
                        break;
                    } else {
                      
                        console.log('In port 3');
                        const saveBtn = document.querySelector("[aria-label='save']");
                        const submitBtn = document.querySelector('[aria-label="submit"]');
                        console.log(submitBtn);
                        if (saveBtn) {
                            saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                                console.log('Save button clicked');
                                const totalBoxes = svgParentContainer.querySelectorAll('rect').length;
                                const finalSheetUploadMessage = {
                                    ...message,
                                    action: 'upload_google_sheet',
                                    boxcount: totalBoxes
                                };
                                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(finalSheetUploadMessage);
                            });
                        }

                        if (submitBtn) {
                            console.log(submitBtn);
                            const totalBoxes = svgParentContainer.querySelectorAll('rect').length;
                            submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                                const sheetUpdateMessage = {
                                    ...message,
                                    action: 'upload_google_sheet',
                                    boxcount: totalBoxes,
                                    submit: 1,
                                    return: 0
                                }
                                console.log('Submit btn was clicked');
                                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(sheetUpdateMessage);
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

if (chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListener(demeterRuntimeCallbackFunction))
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(demeterRuntimeCallbackFunction);
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(demeterRuntimeCallbackFunction);
```

## Working

The website i am scraping has an embedded website inside it as an iframe, so I created another content script for it. What i did was scraped details on the original webpage, then sent those details to the embedded webpage to extract further information there and then I am clustering those information and uploading to my google sheet

here is my workflow
content.js -> background.js -> demeter.js -> upload_google_sheet

I have kept allowload = 1 for automatically update the google sheet once all the page loads. Since several instances of the webpage can be open so I tried to implement tab switch event. So that the extension starts firing messages again from scratch once tab switch happens.

## Problem

I open let say 3 tabs of the website and rapidly switch tabs among them. I get quite a large number of duplicate rows. I did a lot in tracking and removing listeners. But I really can't find the exact solution or approach to solving this. I want that after rapid switching of tabs. I get the information on the current tab only and no information from other tabs.

Since I am very new to stack overflow. Pardon my long question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Along with sharing the whole code, if you could highlight the code snippet causing the problem, it'd be really a great help to those who'll help you.

Comment: Sir, I am having issues with the background.js part, regarding message passing. I found while inspecting in console.. Multilple messages were being passed and multiple copies of messages were created. I want to know just how to prevent that duplication